# expected nil not to be a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

hello community i'm doing an simple application which an user can be able to registrer (as a new user), so im trying to create a new user with my Usercontroller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

def create

    @users = User.new
    if @users.save
      flash[:notice] = 'new user was successfully created.'
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

here is my rspec test user_controller_spec:

```
require 'spec/spec_helper'

describe UserController do

    it "create new user" do
        get :create
        assigns[:users].should_not be_new_record
    end
end
```

when i test it, it show this error:

Failures:

1) UserController create new user

```
 Failure/Error: assigns[:users].should_not be_new_record

   expected nil not to be a new record
 # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:7
```

Finished in 0.15482 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

for last here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :cars
  validates_presence_of  :email

end
```

Comment: Do you have any validations that would prevent .save?

Comment: mmmm no i haven't, where i create it?

Comment: In the model. validates :name, :presence => true

Comment: now that i look around, i have in the model 
validates_presence_of  :email
only that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record isn't saving because it is not valid.
You have a validation that prevents a record from being created without an email address.

Also, your create action has no way to take input from a form.

```
def create
  @users = User.new(params[:user]) # the params[:user] is the part you are missing
  if @users.save
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => 'new user was successfully created.'
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Then, in your test, make sure you assign an email address.

```
get :create, :user => { :email => 'foo@example.com' }
assigns[:users].should_not be_new_record
```

Comment: ok I'm starting to understand. in the params i must put email and user name?

Comment: im sorry i hope you understand i'm new in this

Comment: it's that the best way to create a new user on my app

Comment: if i change the line
assigns[:users].should_not be_new_record
to this
assigns[:users].should be_new_record
don't show any error message

Comment: That's because you are changing the test to make sure the record was not saved. Rspec changes be_new_record to call .new_record? on the @users object, and that will return true if the record has not saved, and false if it has saved to the database.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is this:

```
get :create
```

Rails' resource routing will not route GET requests to the create action, because the create action is meant to have side effects.

To test the create action you'll need to do:

```
post :create, "with" => { "some" => "params" }
```

When testing controllers, it's a good idea to tail `log/test.log`; it'll tell you where the test request got routed, if anywhere.